# FTP not accessible outside of LAN

Tags: networking, ftp, firewall, xampp, filezilla

Ok so I really need some help with this, I have XAMPP installed and am hosting a webiste with it for my friends and i to work on. I am able to see the site just fine and also i am able to get to PHPMyAdmin just fine, BUT my FTP server is only accessible from within my home network. I have a static IP assigned to the computer and i have port 21 open and forwarding to that static address. Clearly i opened the ports right or else i wouldnt be able to see apache or phpmyadmin because i succefully opened 80 and 3306. I have a user and password defined and a home folder assigned to that account. Also in the passive mode settings i have correctly defined my External IP address. And lastly i have made sure that all inbound and outbound rules in the firewall are set to allow the connection, i even tried to connect after completely turning off my windows firewall.

Thanks for any help in advanced, i hope someone thinks of something i didnt.

OH and i almost forgot, i just got a new router recently as the old one got fried in a lightning storm, with the old router, I was able to connect to the FTP just fine, but now after setting up the new one with (what i thought to be) the same settings as the old one, now i am no longer able to see the FTP.

Comment: How are you testing outside network access? If you are inside your network and trying to connect to port 21 using the public IP, that's not gonna work. Some routers are smart enough to realize the public IP is its own IP and redirect the traffic, but most aren't. You need to test this from outside your network to be sure. I would suggest setting up remote administration for your router or install teamviewer on a pc inside the networ, so you can change the config of the router while being outside of the router, to test stuff. It should work.

Comment: Firstly thank you for the -1 with no explanation to whoever left that. Secondly, @LPChip i believe you are correct, stupid me didnt think of that and it seems to be working from my phone and an FTP app over LTE rather than WiFi, Thank you so much, If you would post that as an answer i would be happy to mark it as such

Comment: Be aware that FTP depends on a lot of incoming ports in passive mode (which you want). I recommend using a more firewall-/port-forwarding-friendly protocol, like SFTP. FTPS aka “encrypted FTP” _does not_ help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you testing outside network access? If you are inside your network and trying to connect to port 21 using the public IP, that's not gonna work. Some routers are smart enough to realize the public IP is its own IP and redirect the traffic, but most aren't. You need to test this from outside your network to be sure. I would suggest setting up remote administration for your router or install teamviewer on a pc inside the networ, so you can change the config of the router while being outside of the router, to test stuff. It should work.

Comment: Hmm, good answer, but no upvotes... You point out some good solutions. +1

Answer (score 1):

Even though this is answered and accepted, I'll add my own to be thorough... Using a phone with 3G/4G can also be a nice way to test this.

And, if you are familiar with SSH tunnels and port forwards, you can SSH into a remote machine and use a port forward to, for instance, 3389 (Windows RDC) and then access a remote Windows machine and then FTP back into your local area network:

`ssh -i /path/to/ssh_key user@host -L8181:192.168.x.x:3389`

or whatever your subnet is...

Both of these have helped me a lot in my sysadmin testing...

Comment: I don't have the rep to up vote this, but yes this is a very good idea and since asking this question, I have indeed used the 3G/4G phone method. I have not used the SSH method but it seems to me like a great thought. Thanks!

Comment: Sure, no problem. I just bumped your rep, so feel free to up-vote this answer... Cheers.